# Google App Engine Error 503 - Service Unavailable

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http-status-code-503

For the past couple of days, every time I try to run my web application, Error - 503 has been showing up. This happens even when I try to go to the admin page. Is this a problem with Google?

Comment: If by Admin page, you mean the Dashboard, then yes, if that 503s, then the problem is on Google's end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's important when creating a GAE project that any .class that extends HttpServlet and are used as entry point to your Google App are mapped in web.xml found in war/WEB-INF as pictured below.

[image: Project Hierachy]

Java Servlets you create that extend HttpServlet must be mapped in the web.xml like the following:-

[image: web.xml]

In this Test GAE project ecipse generated sample code that created a Java Servlet called TestServlet.class that extends HttpServlet and is appropriately mapped.

To run your app you need to include the url mapped to the TestServlet.class found in the web.xml (In this case /test) in your index.html. (In the case of generated project sample code created by eclipse this will already have been done).

Once your Java Servlets are correctly mapped in the web.xml and included in your index.html the mapped url that is clicked will invoke the appropriate Servlet and run your app.

This will eliminate common 503 errors in terms of new project setup.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me in getting the Blobstore java API example from google up and running: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/ I was quite surprised that there are no official github project for Google's Blobstore example so it caused me to investigate a bit before the example would work (it was giving me Error 503). Turns out google required us to put in the proper servlet-class names for the web.xml file (ie. <package name>.Upload instead of just Upload).